# How fast cursor.moveToPosition(i) is?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursoradapter

Wondering wether calling `cursor.moveToPosition(i);` will trigger persistent store operation, or just read from a memory cache?

In Android in a `RecycleView Adapter` this is called quite frequently, I do not want to overload system accessing persistent store. Does this risk exist at all?

Does `Cursor cursor = MainActivity.db.rawQuery("Select _id From UserSetting", null);` operation will result a cached result?

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemHolder itemHolder, int i) {

    cursor.moveToPosition(i);
    int i2 = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id");
    final String _id = cursor.getString(i2);
    itemHolder.itemRecordName = _id;
    int i3 = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("text");
    final String text = cursor.getString(i3);
    int i4 = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("userSettingRecordName");
    final String userSettingRecordName = cursor.getString(i4);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a memory window for cursor. but in case of long jumps your code will trigger io operations.
Look for details [CursorWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorWindow.html)